Git-cliff with Hugo hosted at GitLab pages
I would like to implement an automated changelog with git-cliff

https://github.com/orhun/git-cliff
https://git-cliff.org

The changelog is to be integrated into a Hugo project which is to be hosted on GitLab.
Please take a look at my screenshot. There are some errors.
The config does not appear to match the screenshot. The order of elements according to the template should be
<message> (<commit>) by @<user> in #<pr>. In the screenshot it is <message> (#<pr>) (!<image>) (<commit>).
I don't know why the output is not displayed correctly. I have also tested my project on my personal web space and GitLab pages. The result remains the same. Does anyone use GitLab? Is it possible to test the cliff.toml with GitLab?

The round bracket after the issue no. has one space too many (#1 )
also the merge_request no (!1 )
link to the merge requests. I need some lines of code. I don't know how to insert {% for group, commits in commits | filter(attribute="merge_commit", value=false) %} correctly so that (!1) is displayed as a link.
new contributors needs the merge_number after the !

Here an example for a commit message:
git commit -m 'feat: new feature (#1) (!1)'
(#1) for the issue
(!1) for the merge request
The changelog is generated with gitlab-ci.yml:
#
# Hugomods
# Image Tags: https://docker.hugomods.com/docs/tags/#latest
# GitHub: https://github.com/hugomods
# Homepage: https://hugomods.com
#

image: hugomods/hugo:dart-sass-go-git

variables:
  HUGO_ENV: production
  PAGEFIND_VERSION: v1.1.0
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone # clone entire repo instead of reusing workspace
  GIT_DEPTH: 0 # avoid shallow clone to give cliff all the info it need

before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk upgrade
  - apk add --no-cache git-cliff

stages:
  - changelog
  - test
  - deploy

changelog_job:
  stage: changelog
  script:
    - git-cliff -r . > CHANGELOG.md
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - CHANGELOG.md

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - hugo --minify
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - hugo --minify
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    # If you want schedule then comment out this line
    # - if: '$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'

# git-cliff ~ configuration file
# https://git-cliff.org/docs/configuration

[remote.gitlab]
owner = "username"
repo = "test"
token = "glpat-FyJQswdmjfrAW2YWRrqU"

[changelog]
# template for the changelog body
# https://keats.github.io/tera/docs/#introduction
header = """
# Changelog\n
This is an automated changelog based on the commits in this repository.\n

### Releases

Check the notes in the [releases](https://gitlab.com/username/test/-/releases) for more information.
"""
# https://keats.github.io/tera/docs/#introduction
body = """
{% if version -%}\
    ## [{{ version | trim_start_matches(pat="v") }}] - {{ timestamp | date(format="%Y-%m-%d") }}
{% else %}\
    ## [Unreleased]
{% endif -%}\

{% for group, commits in commits | group_by(attribute="group") %}
    ### {{ group | upper_first }}
    {% for commit in commits %}
        - {% if commit.breaking %}[**breaking**] {% endif %}{{ commit.message | upper_first | trim }} ([{{ commit.id | truncate(length=7, end="") }}](<REPO>/commit/{{ commit.id }}))\
            {% if commit.gitlab.username and commit.gitlab.username != remote.gitlab.owner %} by [@{{ commit.gitlab.username }}](https://gitlab.com/{{ commit.gitlab.username }}){%- endif -%}
            {% if commit.gitlab.pr_number %} in [#{{ commit.gitlab.pr_number }}]( <REPO>/-/commit/{{ commit.gitlab.pr_number }}){%- endif -%}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{%- if gitlab.contributors | filter(attribute="is_first_time", value=true) | length != 0 %}
  ## New Contributors
{%- endif -%}

{% for contributor in gitlab.contributors | filter(attribute="is_first_time", value=true) %}
  * [@{{ contributor.username }}](https://gitlab.com/{{ contributor.username }}) made their first contribution in [!{{ contributor.pr_number }}](<REPO>/-/merge_requests/{{ contributor.pr_number }})\
{%- endfor %}\n
"""
# changelog footer
footer = """
{% for release in releases -%}
    {% if release.version -%}
        {% if release.previous.version -%}
            [{{ release.version | trim_start_matches(pat="v") }}]: \
                <REPO>/-/compare/{{ release.previous.version }}...{{ release.version }}
        {% endif -%}
    {% else -%}
        [unreleased]: <REPO>/-/compare/{{ release.previous.version }}...HEAD
    {% endif -%}
{% endfor %}
"""
# remove the leading and trailing whitespace from the template
trim = true
postprocessors = [
  { pattern = '<REPO>', replace = "https://gitlab.com/username/test" }, # replace repository URL
]

[git]
# https://www.conventionalcommits.org
# parse the commits based on https://www.conventionalcommits.org
conventional_commits = true
# filter out the commits that are not conventional
filter_unconventional = true
# process each line of a commit as an individual commit
split_commits = false
# regex for preprocessing the commit messages
commit_preprocessors = [
  # Replace issue numbers
  { pattern = '\((\w+\s)?#([0-9]+)\)', replace = "([#${2}](<REPO>/issues/${2}))" },
  { pattern = '\((\w+\s)?#([0-9]+)\)', replace = "([#${2}](<REPO>/merge_requests/${2}))" },
]
commit_parsers = [
  { message = "^feat", group = "Features" },
  { message = "^fix", group = "Bug Fixes" },
  { message = "^doc", group = "Documentation" },
  { message = "^perf", group = "Performance" },
  { message = "^refactor", group = "Refactor" },
  { message = "^style", group = "Styling" },
  { message = "^test", group = "Testing" },
  { message = "^chore\\(release\\): prepare for", skip = true },
  { message = "^chore\\(deps\\)", skip = true },
  { message = "^chore\\(pr\\)", skip = true },
  { message = "^chore\\(commit\\)", skip = true },
  { message = "^chore|ci", group = "Miscellaneous Tasks" },
  { body = ".*security", group = "Security" },
  { message = "^revert", group = "Revert" },
]
# protect breaking changes from being skipped due to matching a skipping commit_parser
protect_breaking_commits = false
# filter out the commits that are not matched by commit parsers
filter_commits = false
# regex for matching git tags
# tag_pattern = "v[0-9].*"
# regex for skipping tags
# skip_tags = ""
# regex for ignoring tags
# ignore_tags = ""
# sort the tags topologically
topo_order = false
# sort the commits inside sections by oldest/newest order
sort_commits = "newest"
# limit the number of commits included in the changelog.
# limit_commits = 42



